# How to format date elements (year, month, date) individually with CSS and Rails i18n?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

We're using Rails with i18n gem.  It's pretty standard stuff.

With i18n you can define your date format for different languages in the locales yml file.

For example, you can have en.yml

```
date:
    formats:
        long: ! '%-d %b %Y'
```

In your view file, you can do

```
<span class="homepage_date"><%= l Date.today, format: :long %></span>
```

This is all fine.  It would output "10 Oct 2013" string and apply the CSS styling to the
whole string.

However, we have a requirement to format the date elements (date, month, year) individually using different CSS classes.

For example, we want the date "10" in a skinny font, the month "Oct" in a bold font, and the year "2013" in another font.

In another language, the formatting may be different, for example, in Chinese, we want all 3 elements (year, month, date) to be in the same font.

I'm not sure if it's good practice to put CSS in translation yml files.

What's the best solution to meet our requirement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
date:
  formats:
    styled: ! '<span class="day">%-d</span> <span class="month">%b</span> <span class="year">%Y</span>'
```

use that format

```
<span class="date"><%= l Date.today, format: :styled %></span>
```

and then specify css for those classes

```
.date .day {} ...
```

Comment: thank you for your comment.  i'm aware of this way of embedding css in the translation yml file.  this way, formatting and translation are mixed together, though you can argue formatting is part of the localization effort.  ideally, the css formatting should be kept in the view file.  also this way, it's not DRY, as the CSS elements are written into, say, 15-20, translation yml files.  But thanks for the  comment.

Comment: @JeffChau if you have a default locale, you don't have to put it in every translation file. just put it into the default one.

Comment: Looks like in the view file, I have to write <span class="date"><%= l(Date.today, format: :styled).html_safe %></span>, otherwise, html is being displayed on the website, as if it's the literal translation